# How to safely store SQL script in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing text in a database which represents content which will later be used to generate SQL script which will be used for future queries.  I know this is dangerous, however, need this functionality and don't know how else to get it.

When first storing the user provided content, I use a prepare statement, however, feel this is giving a false sense of security.  When I later retrieve the value and use it in a future query, any dangerous user input returns in its original form.

One strategy is to for every future query which uses the content, take appropriate actions with prepared statements, pdo::quote(), etc.  Note that in my below example, I am not doing this and using the potentially dangerous SQL directly in a pdo::query(), and I am concerned that I will one day forget to do this.

Instead, I am thinking of taking action right when I get the data from $_POST.  Is there a way to remove any potential content once and for all, and then store and retrieve it without concern?  If not, acceptable values received from $_POST are an integer, a date, a datetime, or a number and I suppose I can just insure the data falls into one of these data types.

So, to reiterate....

1. How should I best store content which is later used as SQL for future queries?
2. How can I permanently remove content which can be used as SQL injection instead of just escaping it?

Thanks

```
$user_input=$_POST['suspect_user_input']; //Acceptable values are an integer, a date, a datetime, or a number
$sql='INSERT INTO table1 (id,user_input) VALUES(123,?)';
$stmt = db::db()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($user_input));
unset($user_input);
...
...
$sql='SELECT user_input FROM table1 WHERE id=123';
$stmt = db::db()->query($sql);
$user_input=$stmt->fetchColumn();
$partial_select_statement='SELECT * FROM '.$user_input;
$sql='INSERT INTO table2 (id,partial_select_statement) VALUES(321,'.$partial_select_statement.')';
$stmt = db::db()->exec($sql);
unset($partial_select_statement);
...
...
$sql='SELECT partial_select_statement FROM table2 WHERE id=321';
$stmt = db::db()->query($sql);
$partial_select_statement=$stmt->fetchColumn();
$new_sql=$partial_select_statement.' WHERE foo=bar';
$stmt = db::db()->query($new_sql);
$rs=$stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: You can't safely remove the content.  That's the shortfall ofdynamic SQL.  Now, if the SQL is being sourced from within the applicataion, or users are just providing parameters, you can minimize the risk by using a stored procedure to generate the "string" so that the values being passed in are coming in as parameters which helps ensure data type validity and then your building the block, but to remove possible offending content; find a different solution.  Dynamic SQL HAS this shortfall.  however, if your not using string data, SQL injection would be difficult if not impossible.

Comment: @xQbert  Thanks for your reply.  I am unfortunately using string data, but limited to integers, dates, and numbers.  If necessary, I will just ensure that all user data falls into one of those three forms.  Or maybe just strip any quotes with PHP?

Comment: I'd make sure to scrub each data casting it to it's valid data type before attempting to store it; striping quotes can be a good start but there's likely ways around it such as using ascii values which then get interpreted by the database as, you guessed it, quotes.  By casting each data type to a non-string value, you greatly reduce that risk.  Just bear in mind, it can't be eliminated, thus is the nature of Dynamic SQL

Comment: @xQbert.  I knew it was dangerous.  Didn't know it was termed "Dynamic SQL" which will give me a good way to search.  Good point about the quotes.  I will keep it really simple.  Maybe for dates, I will break into year/day/month, type cast to integers, and reassemble.

Comment: Also search for "second order sql injection".